# C++: socket encoding (working with TeamSpeak)

Tags: c++, encoding, listbox

As I'm currently working on a program for a TeamSpeak server, I need to retrieve the names of the currently online users which I'm doing with sockets - that's working fine so far.
In my UI I'm displaying all clients in a ListBox which is basically working. Nevertheless I'm having problems with wrong displayed characters and symbols in the ListBox.
I'm using the following code:

```
//...
auto getClientList() -> void{
    i = 0;
    queryString.str("");
    queryString.clear();
    queryString << clientlist << " \n";
    send(sock, queryString.str().c_str(), strlen(queryString.str().c_str()), NULL);
    TeamSpeak::getAnswer(1);
    while(p_1 != -1){
        p_1 = lastLog.find(L"client_nickname=", sPos + 1);
        if(p_1 != -1){
            sPos = p_1;
            p_2 = lastLog.find(L" ", p_1);
            temporary = lastLog.substr(p_1 + 16, p_2 - (p_1 + 16));
            users[i].assign(temporary.begin(), temporary.end());
            SendMessage(hwnd_2, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)(LPTSTR)(users[i].c_str()));
            i++;
        }
        else{
            sPos = 0;
            p_1 = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    TeamSpeak::getAnswer(0);
}
//...
```

I've already checked `lastLog`, `temporary` and `users[i]` (by writing them to a file), but all of them have no encoding problem with characters or symbols (for example `Andrè`). If I add a string directly:
`SendMessage(hwnd_2, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)(LPTSTR)L"Andrè"`, it is displayed correctly in the ListBox.
**What might be the issue here, is it a problem with my code or something else?**

---

**Update 1:**
I recently continued working on this problem and considered the word `Olè!` receiving it from the socket. The result I got, is the following:
`O (79) | l (108) | � (-61) | � (-88) | ! (33)`.
**How can I convert this `char array` to a `wstring` containing the correct characters?**

---

**Solution:**
 As @isanae mentioned in his post, the `std::wstring_convert`-template did the trick for me, thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by, "wrong displayed characters and symbols in the ListBox"?

Comment: Without more details about the only thing that comes to mind is you have an Ansi/Unicode mismatch (e.g. the control is Ansi, but you're feeding it a Unicode string).

Comment: Sorry, I added some more details.

Comment: What's the type of `users`? `string` or `wstring`?

Comment: I'm guessing that `lastLog` was built from the read of a network socket, which returns a byte stream, and that byte stream is converted to wide characters. The conversion is wrong, but matches the code page that Windows assumes for text files so it looks right when you write it to a file.

Comment: @MarkRansom `users` is `wstring`. Is there a possible solution then, because it's not possible to retrieve wide characters from the socket, is it?

Comment: Is this compiled with the "Unicode" or "Multi-Byte" character set in the project options?

Comment: It is compiled with the "Unicode" character set.

Comment: [`mbstowcs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx) should do the conversion properly.

Comment: Sadly `mbstowcs` didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things can go wrong in this code, and you don't show much of it. What's particularly lacking is the definition of all those variables.

Assuming that `users[i]` contains meaningful data, you also don't say how it is encoded. Is it ASCII? UTF-8? UTF-16? The fact that you can output it to a file and read it with an editor doesn't mean anything, as most editors are able to guess at encoding.

If it really is UTF-16 (the native encoding on Windows), then I see no reason for this code not to work. One way to check would be to break into the debugger and look at the individual bytes in `users[i]`. If you see every character with a value less than 128 followed by a 0, then it's probably UTF-16.

If it is not UTF-16, then you'll need to convert it. There are a variety of ways to do this, but [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be the easiest. Make sure you set the `codepage` to same encoding used by the sender. It may be `CP_UTF8`, or an [actual codepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note also that hardcoding a string with non-ASCII characters doesn't help you much either, as you'd first have to find out the encoding of the file itself. I know some versions of Visual C++ will convert your source file to UTF-16 if it encounters non-ASCII characters, which may be what happened to you.

> `O (79) | l (108) | � (-61) | � (-88) | ! (33)`.
>
> How can I convert this char array to a wstring containing the correct characters?

This is a UTF-8 string. It has to be converted to UTF-16 so Windows can use it.

This is a portable, C++11 solution on implementations where `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`. If this is not the case, then `char16_t` and `std::u16string` may be used, but the most recent version of Visual C++ as of this writing (2015 RC) doesn't implement `std::codecvt` for `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring utf8_to_utf16(const std::string& s)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(wchar_t)==2, "wchar_t needs to be 2 bytes");
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(s);
}

std::string utf16_to_utf8(const std::wstring& s)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(wchar_t)==2, "wchar_t needs to be 2 bytes");
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}
```

Windows-only:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <codecvt>
#include <Windows.h>

std::wstring utf8_to_utf16(const std::string& s)
{
    // getting the required size in characters (not bytes) of the
    // output buffer
    const int size = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), static_cast<int>(s.size()),
        nullptr, 0);

    // error handling
    assert(size != 0);

    // creating a buffer with enough characters in it
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buffer(new wchar_t[size]);

    // converting from utf8 to utf16
    const int written = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), static_cast<int>(s.size()),
        buffer.get(), size);

    // error handling
    assert(written != 0);

    return std::wstring(buffer.get(), buffer.get() + written);
}

std::string utf16_to_utf8(const std::wstring& ws)
{
    // getting the required size in bytes of the output buffer
    const int size = ::WideCharToMultiByte(
        CP_UTF8, 0, ws.c_str(), static_cast<int>(ws.size()),
        nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);

    // error handling
    assert(size != 0);

    // creating a buffer with enough characters in it
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[size]);

    // converting from utf16 to utf8
    const int written = ::WideCharToMultiByte(
        CP_UTF8, 0, ws.c_str(), static_cast<int>(ws.size()),
        buffer.get(), size, nullptr, nullptr);

    // error handling
    assert(written != 0);

    return std::string(buffer.get(), buffer.get() + written);
}
```

Test:

```
// utf-8 string
const std::string s = {79, 108, -61, -88, 33};

::MessageBoxW(0, utf8_to_utf16(s).c_str(), L"", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Sorry for being so unspecific about `users[i]`. It's an array of `wstrings` which is empty at the beginning of the function. And later on as you can see it gets filled with the usernames.

Comment: `users` might be an array, but `users[i]` is definitely not. In any case, do you now know the encoding of the data?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself a little bit wrong there. Nevertheless I do not know how the user names are encoded, I received them through a socket.

Comment: You seem to be communicating with a TS server using an SDK. Does it have any information on how it encodes strings? Can you show us the values of, let's say, the first 20 bytes of the response? We might be able to guess the encoding.

Comment: I'm communicating with an TS, but without using an SDK, just sockets. Anyways how should I show you the answer? I can write it in a file, but that's not helpful, is it?

Comment: `for (std::size_t c=0; c<20; ++c) std::cout << static_cast<int>(users[i][c]) << " ";`

Comment: These are the bytes of the first username: 
83 111 116 104 116 104 105 112 97 108 97 0

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no non-ASCII character in it. Did you try `MultiByteToWideChar()` with `CP_UTF8`?

Comment: I did, but it had no different effect than before.

Comment: Then give us more information, more code and more data. I can't help you further.